# ANTLR fetch comment text for additional processing

Tags: parsing, comments, antlr, lexer

In an experimental language development, need to fetch the comment text for further processing.

At the tokens level this does not work,

```
COMMENT      : comm = ('/*' ~'*' .* '*/')  { System.out.println($comm.text); } ;
```

Tried to add statement and/or expression, yet this desired syntax is not parsed either,

```
x = myFunction(x1, /* comment x1 */
               x2, /* comment x2 */
               x3)
```

**Update**: using ANTLR 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this working approach though not fully sound as of associating a statement/expression to a comment,

```
@lexer::members {   
    public static final int COMMENTS = 2;
}
```

and so comments are deviated to numbered channel,

```
COMMENT      : '/*' ~'*' .* '*/' {$channel=COMMENTS;} ;
```

Then,

```
NetworkLexer lexer = new NetworkLexer(sourceStream);
CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

Parser parser = new Parser(tokenStream);
parser.prog();
```

To fetch the comment text with line numbers consider this Java code,

```
for (Object tk: tokenStream.getTokens()) {
  CommonToken ctk = (CommonToken) tk;
  if (ctk.getChannel() == 2) {
    if (ctk.getText() != null && ctk.getText().trim().isEmpty() == false) {
      System.out.println(String.format("tk channel %s line %s text %s"), 
                               ctk.getChannel(), ctk.getLine(), ctk.getText());
  }
}
```